# Split every vector in a sequence into two parts: old elements that were contained in previous vectors and new elements never before seen

Tags: lisp, clojure

Am I doing it right? Is there some function in the standard library I should be using? This is my first real(ish) world Clojure program…

## Input

```
(def data
  [[{:id 5 :name "a"} {:id 1 :name "b"}], [{:id 4 :name "c"} {:id 1 :name "d"}]])
```

## Code

The elements are maps and they are compared based on their `:id`.

```
(def precomputed
  (reductions
   (fn [global, v]
     (let [seen? (:seen? global)
           new   (remove #(-> % :id seen?) v)
           old   (filter #(-> % :id seen?) v)]
       {:seen? (clojure.set/union seen? (->> new (map :id) (set)))
        :new   new
        :old   old}))
   {:seen? #{} :new '() :old '()}
   data))
```

At this moment `precomputed` looks like

```
({:seen? #{}, :new (), :old ()}
{:seen? #{1 5}, :new ({:id 5, :name "a"} {:id 1, :name "b"}), :old ()}
{:seen? #{1 4 5}, :new ({:id 4, :name "c"}), :old ({:id 1, :name "d"})})
```

Print some sort of output

```
(doseq [i (rest precomputed)]
  (println "new: " (->> (i :new) (map :name) (interpose ", ") (reduce str))
           "old: " (->> (i :old) (map :name) (interpose ", ") (reduce str))))
```

## Output

```
new:  a, b old:     ; first vector, every element is new
new:  c old:  d     ; we have seen element with :id 1 before
```

Comment: Does this all work as intended?  If so, what would you like reviewed?

Comment: @Jamal Uh. Am I doing it right? Is there some function in the standard library I should be using? This is my first real(ish) world Clojure program…

Comment: You can put that into the question, then.

Comment: You could probably use [`partition-all`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-all) to partition the input into the two outputs.

Comment: @ferada I am partitioning based on a predicate, not splitting the sequence into partitions of a given size, which is what partition-all seems to be doing. But, I guess I can improve the partitioning based on this SO question [Clojure partition by filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664833/clojure-partition-by-filter)

Comment: @user7610 yes sorry, that was the wrong link, [`split-with`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/split-with) should do though.

Comment: `split-with` wouldn't work here, as it is equivalent to `take-while`/`drop-while` and not `filter`/`remove`. What you really looking for is *probably* `group-by`, such that `(let [m (group-by #(-> % :id seen?) v), old (m true), new (m false)] ...)`

Answer (score 1):

### Concatenating a sequence of strings

[You should use `(apply str)` instead of `(reduce str)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395862/2268996) As `str` can take multiple arguments, and `apply` can take a sequence as a second argument. Intermediate results generated by `reduce` would cause time and space waste.

Since you are using a separator string, use [clojure.string/join](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/join) instead:

```
(->> (i :new) (map :name) (clojure.string/join ", "))
```

### Naming loop vars

In the above code `i` is not a good name, I expect `i` to be some kind of index. If using meaningful names like `user`, `order` is not available; you can user `curr` for current `m` for map as temporary variables. Important point is [principle of least surprise](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment).

### Map destructuring

You can also use [map destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20%28Destructuring%29-Map%20binding%20destructuring). It is easiest to show it by example:

```
> (doseq [{:keys [new old]} [{:new 1 :old 2} {:new 3 :old 4}]] (prn old new old))
2 1 2
4 3 4
```

So similarly here:

```
(doseq [{:keys [new old]} (rest precomputed)]
  (println "new: " (->> new (map :name) (clojure.string/join ", "))
           "old: " (->> old (map :name) (clojure.string/join ", "))))
```

### Prefer functions over constants

Prefer functions over data. Functions are the basic unit of re-use in clojure. It will be obvious if you try to test `precomputed` you provided, with multiple example data (in REPL by hand or with [run-tests](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/run-tests)). Other signs `precomputed` should be a function is:

- it's name: `precomputed` implies a function by name `precompute` should exist (also/instead).
- `data` is only referred to once, right at the end; and the rest of the form doesn't depend on it.

### Decompose `precomputed`

See values in `precomputed` does not depend on the previous values of `:new` and `:old` but only those of `:seen?`.

It can be rewritten thus:

```
(defn seen-ids [data]
  (reductions
      #(clojure.set/union %1 (->> %2 (map :id) set))
    #{}
    data))
```

You don't need to put parens around `set`.

You can then get new and old elements separately:

```
(defn new-elts [seen-ids data]
  (map (fn [seen? v] (remove #(-> % :id seen?) v)) seen-ids data))
```

### Terse function definition

Sometimes you may want to define a function as combination of other functions instead of using `fn`. Combinators clojure has for this purpose are `comp`, `partial`, and `juxt`.

For example `#(-> % :id seen?)` is equivalent to `(comp %1 :id)`, which also allows the `fn` to be replaced by `#`. You can sometimes use `partial` to define functions w/o using parameter names, but **I do not recommend it to use in top level functions**, as parameter names are important developer documentation; but this style may be useful for shortening inline definitions (in `let`, `for` etc).

`old-elts` can be defined using this style, like this (compare with the definition of `new-elts` above):

```
(def old-elts (partial map #(filter (comp %1 :id) %2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tackling the problem afresh, you can accomplish the heart of the computation as follows:

```
(let [ids (map (partial map :id) data)
      seens (reductions into #{} ids)
      classes (map (fn [s ms] (group-by (comp nil? s :id) ms)) seens data)]
  (map
   (partial map-kv (fn [k v] [({true :new, false :old} k) (map :name v)]))
   classes))
```

... which produces

```
({:new ("a" "b")} {:new ("c"), :old ("d")})
```

To see how it works, look at `ids`, `seens`, and `classes` for a number of values of `data`.

All the functions employed are standard, except for

```
(defn map-kv
  "Returns the map resulting from applying the function
  f to each of the entries of map m. f must return a 
  key-value pair (a two-element sequence)."
  [f m]
  (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] (f k v)) m)))
```

... which is lifted from the [Clojure Cookbook, section 2.21](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-21_applying-functions-to.asciidoc). I've swapped the arguments around to comply with the convention that collection arguments figure last in `map` and its variants.

This lazy version is likely to be quite a bit slower than one using loop/recur.